# stringstream good() return value with char vs. string

Tags: c++, stringstream

I would like to understand why `ss.good()` behavior is different when `z` below is a `std::string` vs. `char`, in particular why `good()` returns `true` in one case and `false` with other.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
   std::string line;
   while (getline(std::cin, line)) {
      std::cout << "Reading new line Size " << line.size() << "\n";
      std::stringstream ss{line};
      std::string z; // switch later to char
      ss >> z;
      if (ss.good()) {
         std::cout << "Stream good\n";
      } else {
         std::cout << "Not good\n";
      }
   }

}
```

With `std::string z`, the program output is

```
$ ./a.out
A
Reading new line Size 1
Not good
```

With `char z`, the program output is

```
$ ./a.out
A
Reading new line Size 1
Stream good
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the other status functions, I'm sure the difference is in `ss.eof()`.

Reading a `char` only ever tries to read one character, and doesn't notice if there is anything more in the stream.

Comment: Indeed it has to do with EOF being set with string and not char.